# emulate pbewithmd5anddes in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, md5, des

I made a password generating program some time ago in java.
it generated passwords based on an input string and password.
it used: pbewithMD5andDES

now i'm making a new version of this for mobile devices in javascript.
i found the library crypto-js witch allows me to generate MD5-hashes and encrypt using DES

but i can't seem to generate identical passwords

what am i doing wrong?

java version:

```
 public static String generate(String password, String passphase) throws Exception {
    try {
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphase.toCharArray());
        PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec;
        SecretKeyFactory keyFac;
        // Salt
        byte[] salt = {(byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x99};
        // Iteration count
        int count = 20;
        // Create PBE parameter set
        pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);
        keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        // Create PBE Cipher
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        // Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
        // Our cleartext
        byte[] cleartext = password.getBytes();
        // Encrypt the cleartext
        byte[] ciphertext = pbeCipher.doFinal(cleartext);
        return byteArrayToHexString(ciphertext).substring(0, 12);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        int v = b[i] & 0xff;
        if (v < 16) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
    }
    return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

the new javascript version (not compete): (i tried both orders: first hashing then DES, and the oher way around)

```
var hashedPassword = CryptoJS.MD5(password);
var encryptedPassword = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(hashedPassword, passphrase).toString();
var result = encryptedPassword.toString().substring(0, 12).toUpperCase();
```

am i on the right way?

Comment: A few sidenotes: 1) DES is pretty weak 2) Constant salts are a bad idea 3) Single iteration hashes are weak as KDF.

Comment: You should look into encoding issues. For example its possible that Java uses UTF16 and js uses UTF8 (or similar encoding differences). It's also possible that java doesn't use plain MD5, but rather a MD5 based KDF.

Comment: but the general idea of applying md5 first and then DES should emulate PBEWithMD5AndDES, right? (the next version of this program uses SHA256 and AES :D)

Comment: Plain SHA256 would be almost as bad as plain MD5. Use salt and strengthening (for example PBKDF2).